# How to extract json values in php using file_get_contents

Tags: php, json

I have a web page in json format, whose url is: http://radiojoven.6te.net/teste/now.json.

I've been researching ways to extract the information I want, using echo php. I made a code, but I'm not able to extract the information I want, which is "song_name": "MAKIN' WHOOPEE","artist_name": "YANNICK BOVY".

Attached, I show the code so that you can tell me where my error is:

```php
<?php
    $content = file_get_contents("http://radiojoven.6te.net/teste/now.json");
    $content = utf8_encode($content);
    $result = json_decode($content, true);

    $url = $result['zenon']['song_name'];
    
    echo $url;
?>

<?php
    $content = file_get_contents("http://radiojoven.6te.net/teste/now.json");
    $content = utf8_encode($content);
    $result = json_decode($content, true);

    $url = $result['zenon']['artist_name'];
    
    echo $url;
?>
```

Is there any way to remove the remaining "song_name" and "artist_name", I try to use ['artist_name'][1] (...) with no result.

Thank you very much for your attention and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you to use **Curl** instead of **file_get_contents**.

If you want to keep using **file_get_contents** this is the way to do it:

```php
    $content = file_get_contents("http://radiojoven.6te.net/teste/now.json");
    $content = utf8_encode($content);
    $result = json_decode($content, true);
    $currentSongName = $result["now_playing_record"][0]['zenon']['song_name'];
    $currentArtistName = $result["now_playing_record"][0]['zenon']['artist_name'];

    echo $currentArtistName . " | " . $currentSongName;
```

In case you want to switch to **Curl** you can use this

```php
    $url = "http://radiojoven.6te.net/teste/now.json";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $result = json_decode($result, true);
    $result = json_decode(json_encode($result), FALSE);

    $currentSongName = $result->now_playing_record[0]->zenon->song_name;
    $currentArtistName = $result->now_playing_record[0]->zenon->artist_name;

    echo $currentArtistName . " | " . $currentSongName;
```

**Note:** The code is not checking if there is no song playing at all.

Comment: Thank you, @Mootje.

That's what I wanted, I was getting lost on the way to the source. But with his help, I was able to realize my mistake.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

its the other way round?

you have to [1]['artist_name'] instead of ['artist_name'][1]?

because you have a list of played entries each has a artist_name

the correct access would be:

```
$url = $result['now_playing_record'][0]['zenon']['artist_name'];
```

Comment: Thank you @Charliexyx .

She was calling it wrong. But with the explanation I already realized my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to access the values using invalid keys. You're attempting to access `$result['zenon']['song_name']` but the correct path to access these values is `$result['now_playing_record'][0]['zenon']['song_name']` for the first record in the array. Try this

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://radiojoven.6te.net/teste/now.json");
$content = utf8_encode($content);
$result = json_decode($content, true);

// Check if 'now_playing_record' exists and is an array
if (isset($result['now_playing_record']) && is_array($result['now_playing_record'])) {
    // Loop through each record in 'now_playing_record'
    foreach ($result['now_playing_record'] as $record) {
        // Check if 'zenon' exists within the record
        if (isset($record['zenon'])) {
            $songName = $record['zenon']['song_name'];
            $artistName = $record['zenon']['artist_name'];
            echo "Song Name: " . $songName . "<br>";
            echo "Artist Name: " . $artistName . "<br>";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Unable to fetch song and artist information.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you @ Hassu.

Another code that helped me reach the final destination.